# ASP.NET Membership: any way to reset password question and answer in code?

Tags: asp.net, membership

It seems there should be some way for a user to reset his security q and a but I can't find anything. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `GetUser`, it returns a MembershipUser object, on that object is a method `ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer()` which is used to update the question and answer.